# Why Html Fieldset Legend not showing properly in safari browser or Ionic app run in iphones?

Tags: html, css, ionic4

I'm creating Ionic 4 Angular app, and using Html Fieldset. But Html Fieldset not showing properly in safari browser as well as iphones.

```css
.Legend_css { . /* This is lagend css class use in html */
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    padding: 6px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16.16px;
    letter-spacing: 0.15 normal;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-left: 58px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(92, 111, 123, 0.829);
    background: rgba(92, 111, 123, 0.829);
    height: 30px;
    width: 240px;
  }
```

[image: This is how legend show]

Comment: Is that the css for the fieldset or for the legend?

Comment: This is for legend css

Comment: try removing alpha from your legend’s background. Safari is not friends with RGBA...

Answer (score 0):

There is a known problem with alpha channel support. See here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/advanced#known-limitations

To triage this problem try not using RGBA values first and see if it renders correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove `position` and `top` css properties. See my code below.

```css
.Legend_css { . /* This is lagend css class use in html */
    padding: 6px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16.16px;
    letter-spacing: 0.15 normal;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-left: 58px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(92, 111, 123, 0.829);
    background: rgba(92, 111, 123, 0.829);
    height: 30px;
    width: 240px;
  }
```

```html
<fieldset style="height:250px;">
<legend class="Legend_css">ABCDE</legend>
</fieldset>
```